# How do you store a watch value into a variable in your program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lets say I am debugging and I have a variable as such

```
bytes[] x = new byte[]{0x00, 0x01, 0x02}
```

I perform some calculations on this variable and now in the debugger I can see that my variable x has changed. How can I copy the values of the **entire** variable x and use it for later testing.

For example, in the watch window, after my calculations x is now an array of 585 bytes. So I want a variable in my program as

```
bytes[] newx = new byte{All the 585 bytes here}
```

I know that I can select each individual byte, and copy it one by one to form a new variable, I am wondering if there is a smarter way to go about doing this?

I would ideally like to save that value and use that variable in later places like unit tests etc, so I really do not want to keep performing the calculations just to get the newx value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize the variable, write it to a file from the Immediate Window, like :

```
File.WriteAllText(@"path",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bytes));
```

Then when you need it back, just deserialize it like

```
bytes=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(File.ReadAllText(@"path"));
```

You can use other serializer depending on your needs, for small objects you can even just use Base64 and copy-paste them manually, on a larger object the binary serializer can be faster/take less RAM.

While the Immediate Window can toggle past command histories, if you often write and load, it might be worth it to write a dedicated static helper class to call from anywhere, so you can very quickly call, say

```
Save(bytes,"whatevername");
```

and

```
bytes=Load<byte[]>("whatevername");
```

Comment: Thanks, This piece of code did the trick. I wonder if Visual Studio has something native that could help us with this. It sounds like a really good feature to have.

Comment: It's kinda niche functionality, I think. When I'm developing a new library and need to often manually change the value I'd just add a serializer and initialize the value on the test unit. There's https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter though it doesn't have a built-in importer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the extension, I will definitely find it most useful.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really fully  understand the question but im gonna answer by what i got from it, so your question is how can you store values from an old array into a new one right? if thats the case then then i would use a for loop but the thing is about for loops is that you cant do anything to change the array but only to loop through it so you'll have to use a list and to do that you'll have to use `System.Collections.Generic;` to import lists into your script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

bytes[] x = new byte[]{...};
List<bytes> newx = new List<bytes>{};

for(int i=0; i<x.Length; i++){
    newx.Add(x[i]);
}
```

Comment: actually, your code is coping the byte in memory, when you stop the program, both x and newx will no longer exist. What I was asking was for a way to persist the new x value in a field.